# How to express "just because ... doesn't mean ..." in colloquial French ?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique

Am I correct in assuming that you can express this idea in the following two different ways? The sentence structure of 1B and 2B seems more complicated than 1A and 2A, but do they mean the same thing?

---

Sentence 1: "Just because our technology isn’t quite as advanced doesn’t mean it’s impossible."

> 1A. « Notre technologie n'est pas assez avancée, mais ça ne veut pas dire que c'est impossible. »
>
> 1B. « Ce n'est pas parce que notre technologie n'est pas assez avancée que c'est impossible. »

---

Sentence 2: "Just because I help Camille out every now and then, it doesn’t mean you can eat for free, you know!"

> 2A. « Je rends service à Camille de temps en temps, mais ça ne veut pas dire que tu peux manger à l'œil, tu sais ! »
>
> 2B. « Ce n'est pas parce que je rends service à Camille de temps en temps que tu peux manger à l'œil, tu sais ! »

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tout à fait correct ! A et B signifient la même choses dans les deux phrases retenues.

Dans les phrases A, proches du mot à mot, le *mais* est superflu : c'est un *mais* de défense que je ne détecte pas dans la phrase anglaise :

- si vous le supprimez vous constatez une situation,
- si vous le laissez vous essayez de vous justifier.

Les phrases B sont des transpositions intéressantes, très 'françaises' ; elles peuvent venir à l'esprit dans une conversation.

Comment: Si on veut supprimer les « mais » pour rendre les 2 phrases « A » moins défensives/plus constatives, est-ce que l’on peut ajuter quelque chose au début (comme « Si » ou « Que », par exemple) sans changer l’idée originale des phrases anglaises (et sans redevenant défensives) ? (e.g., « *[Même] Si* X, ça ne veut pas dire Y. »  ou « *[Le fait] Que* X ne veut pas dire [que] Y… . »)

Comment: Je préfère les phrases "B" qui ressemblent bien plus à ce qui me vient naturellement à l'esprit. Cependant avec l'ajout que propose Papa Poule, il m'arrive d'entendre les "A".

Comment: Petite précision sur "you know". En français il est bien plus courant d'entendre "tu vois" que "tu sais" (Bien que ce soit d'un niveau de langage plus bas) Pire encore, il arrive d'entendre "t'as vu?"